# Was the character limit on tag wikis lowered?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

On SO, the PHP wiki was a bit... long. Anyways, people love to make minor tweaks when new versions come out. I went to prune some old material, when I got an error stating there was a hard limit of 30,000 characters for the wiki. You can [see I had to take a chainsaw to it to get it in](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607050/revisions) (it was bloated so this was a good excuse).

The previous revision had about 34,000 characters, and was made 7 hours ago, so this was probably deployed just now.

Was this an intentional change today? Does it apply to Meta tag wikis as well?

Comment: Question bodies had always been 30k already, right? For most sites, that is.

Comment: @Mast I thought so, but [revision 470 has about 34k chars](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607050/470) and was made 7 hours ago

Comment: I vaguely remember not all characters are equal, but I can't find the post about it. May have been a different platform...

Comment: Anyway, I'd suggest you limit your question to the actual question and leave the feature-request for a separate post. One may have triggered the other, but essentially they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Mast yeah, I was about to say the same thing. Something with a client side check, server-side encoding-fu and a database that stores stuff in UCS-2, ramblings

Comment: It's been 30K for a while: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323051/are-tag-excerpts-too-long-or-am-i-just-in-a-hurry-to-get-off-the-elevator

Comment: ugh, finally. ty Machavity, the bloat was becoming... bloaty.